# Play video from System.Io.Stream Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Is there currently a NuGet package for Xamarin Forms that allows you to play videos from a System.Io.Stream object? I have played about with the MediaManager plugin but cannot get the player to work. I am using it in the shared project and also can't find a way to procedurally generate VideoViews in the codebehind (the docs only show how to add to Xaml and bind from the codebehind which isn't what i'm looking for)

Comment: "cannot get the player to work" - this is not a helpful description of the problem.  What have you tried?  What specific problem are you having?  Where is the relevant code?

Comment: @Jason I believe I have worded my question badly. I am not looking for a solution to my issue with MediaManager, I was just saying that I have tried that. What I am looking to find out is if anyone in the community knows any NuGet Packages that allow you to play video's from System.Io.Stream objects (I'm using firebase and this is the format the videos are fetched in). I shall reword my question so it's a little bit less ambiguous

Comment: asking for recommendations for software, tools, etc is explicitly against the SO guidelines

Comment: @Jason bit of a silly rule if you ask me but there you go (Do NuGet packages even come under that branch as I would've thought the purpose of the rule was to stop people asking silly questions like "What software is best to use for editing photos for my app" which obviously developers aren't going to specialise in). Nevertheless, I shall mark the thread as solved as I have worked my own solution. Thanks, Matthew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A easy way is to save the web video link in the firebase and play it with url.
If you saved the stream in the firebase, you could read the stream and save it into storage to play it with file path.

MediaManager: https://github.com/Baseflow/XamarinMediaManager

If you read the stream from Firebase Database, you could google for the Xamarin.forms firebase realtime database. You would find a lot of samples.

After saving the stream into storage (I use `Xamarin.Essentials.FileSystem.AppDataDirectory` for example), you could play the video like below.

The path of `Xamarin.Essentials.FileSystem.AppDataDirectory`:

```
/data/user/0/Package name/files/
```

The code:

```
private async void play_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string filename = "video.mp4";
    var path = Path.Combine(Xamarin.Essentials.FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, filename);

    await CrossMediaManager.Current.Play(path);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this is my current solution (Except i'm using the Xamarin.Community.Toolkit MediaElement to display the video). I have found that in my situation, waiting for the videos to download is not really suitable and so grabbing the URL instead and letting the MediaElement handle downloads is the solution that I will be running with. Thanks!